# Analyze float value in gdb

Tags: gdb

Sample code:

```
int main()
{
        float x = 456.876;

        printf ("\nx = %f\n", x);

        return 0;
}
```

In gdb, I executed this code like this:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at sample_float.c:5   
5               float x = 456.876;   
(gdb) n    
7               printf ("\nx = %f\n", x);   
(gdb) p &x   
$1 = (float *) 0x7fffffffd9dc   
(gdb) x/4fb &x   
0x7fffffffd9dc: 33      112     -28     67
```

Is it possible to see the value at address of x, using: x/fb command as: 456.876?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps I am misreading your question but you can simply do

```
p/f x
```

Or

```
x/f &x
```

Is that what you were looking for ?

Comment: Or `x/fw &x` if you really want to be more explicit about the size.

Comment: in my case this example  displays 2 digits after point. But what if I need more??

Answer (score 2):

agree with the above answer, but to understand why you got the results that you did.

```
(gdb) x/4fb &x   
0x7fffffffd9dc: 33      112     -28     67
```

from the gdb manual

> `x/3uh 0x54320' is a request to display three halfwords (h) of memory, formatted as unsigned decimal integers (`u'), starting at address 0x54320.

thus, x/4fb &x is formatting a byte as a float 4 times. **not** 4 bytes as a float.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link to examining memory using gdb](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_9.html#SEC56)

```
You can use the command x (for "examine") to examine memory in any of several formats, 
independently of your program's data types.

x/nfu addr
x addr
x
n, f, and u are all optional parameters that specify how much memory to display and how to format it; addr is an expression giving the address where you want to start displaying memory. If you use defaults for nfu, you need not type the slash `/'. Several commands set convenient defaults for addr.

n, the repeat count

The repeat count is a decimal integer; the default is 1. It specifies how much memory (counting by units u) to display.

f, the display format

The display format is one of the formats used by print, `s' (null-terminated string), or `i' (machine instruction). The default is `x' (hexadecimal) initially. 
The default changes each time you use either x or print.

 u, the unit size The unit size is any of
 b: Bytes.
 h: Halfwords (two bytes).
 w: Words (four bytes). This is the initial default.
 g: Giant words (eight bytes).
```